# Kali linux internet suddenly working

Tags: vmware, internet, kali-linux

I have been running Kali linux on vmplayer and internet was not working on it. But suddenly today it started working. I didn't install any compat drivers and my laptop is not hooked up to ethernet but still I can access the internet.

Also no wireless connections show up upon typing: `ifconfig` just `eth0` and `lo`.

Can someone please explain how it could be working all of a sudden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual machines inside vmware player do not access hardware directly: vmware emulates hardware for you, providing a virtual ethernet device and bridging/NATing it to the external network device by default. This explains why you don't need drivers for your wireless card and why ifconfig only shows `eth0` and `lo`.

As for the "all of a sudden" part: I assume you didn't change anything in the configuration for the virtual machine, neither in vmplayer virtual network configuration. Did you change any settings in the routing for the host machine? Did you move to a network which has a DHCP (while before that you were testing without DHCP)? Did you by chance had internet connection all along but didn't realize until now?

Comment: No I did not change anything before but I have downloaded compat drivers and now the wireless interface is visible.